# WCF: .NET 2.0, multiple bindings, same port, HTTP, and HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, c#-2.0, wcf-binding

We have a project that has quite a few bindings in IIS. Think something like:

http://www.domain1.com
http://www.domain2.com
http://www.domain3.com

...and so on and so forth. Since this is an e-commerce site, each binding (HTTP) has to have a accompanying HTTPS binding, which means:

https://www.domain1.com
https://www.domain2.com
https://www.domain3.com

These sites have a few WCF services that the front end consumes by way of jQuery. No redirects can happen (i.e. if domain2.com is requested, it has to serve domain2.com's content).

The problem arises is that it's a .NET 2.0 site. We can't upgrade to 4.0 and utilize the multipleSiteBindingsEnabled attribute of the serviceHostingEnvironment node. Otherwise it would work perfectly.

Assuming we have a service as such:
/service/TestService.svc/DoSomething

...how can the following be accomplished?

- http://www.domain1.com/service/TestService.svc/DoSomething
- https://www.domain1.com/service/TestService.svc/DoSomething
- http://www.domain2.com/service/TestService.svc/DoSomething
- https://www.domain2.com/service/TestService.svc/DoSomething
- http://www.domain3.com/service/TestService.svc/DoSomething
- https://www.domain3.com/service/TestService.svc/DoSomething

...with all working and responding properly?

Comment: Have you tried to add https bindings in IIS?

Comment: Yes, https bindings were added in IIS. Created self signed certificates. I can get the site to work for http://www.domain1.com as well as https://www.domain1.com, but the other domains when requesting the service return a 404.

Comment: try to set host headers for bindings :`appcmd set site /site.name: domainN /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='domainN:443:']`

Comment: @user854301, those host headers have been added for every domain. That's what I meant about bindings in the post.

Comment: Does each domain have its own IP address associated or is it some kind of load balanced to redirect traffic to a specific website

Comment: No load balancer. We're using an ecommerce platform that uses the domain name to return the appropriate product catalog. IP address is the same across the board.